# T-SQL to PL-SQL - Using count to return the number of records and the search result using the same query

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql

I'm using that query in SQL Server, and it's working great:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person " +
"WHERE (@Nome IS NULL OR Nome LIKE @Nome + '%') " +
"ORDER BY [Nome] " +
"OFFSET " + pageSize * (pageNumber - 1) + " ROWS " +
"FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS ONLY " +
" " +
"SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Person " +
"WHERE (@Nome IS NULL OR Nome LIKE @Nome + '%') AND Ativo = 1";
```

In this search I return the results along with the total of these results. The output is a all the records with a "No column name" with the total.

But I couldn't find a way to return this result using Oracle.

In the query below, I return the results, but I didn't find a way to use "count" to return the total, along with the values.

ORACLE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM rnum, b.* 
     FROM 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM Person 
          WHERE (:Nome IS NULL OR NOME LIKE ':Nome%')
         ) b 
    ) 
WHERE RNUM between :PageSize * (:PageNumber - 1) AND  (:PageSize * :PageNumber)";
```

Comment: These are 2 different queries. You can do the 2 queries in Oracle, and by the way, Oracle supports the offset .... syntax, no need for you to translate that to rownum ....

Comment: NOME LIKE ':Nome%' has the variable name in quotes. That doesn't work any better in Oracle than it does in SQL Server. Don't quote the variable name.